# WPF Bind to ViewModel of another element

Tags: wpf, binding, viewmodel

Just an example. The CustomControl has a ViewModel with a property called "Test"

How could I bind the textbox to that specific property?
Can you access the siblings ViewModel?

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=ViewModel.Test}"></TextBox>
<Controls:CustomControl x:Name="myControl" />
```

Comment: Does your CustomControl actually have a _dependency property_ called ViewModel?

Comment: doesn't have to be dependency property @Henk Holterman

Comment: No it didn't, adding a DP to it made it work!

Comment: I mean it could have been a normal property as well in that case the control would have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged however all of that is unnecessary when you can bind to DataContext property already

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Siblings ViewModel would be in its DataContext try

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=DataContext.Test}"></TextBox>
<Controls:CustomControl x:Name="myControl" />
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks for the help, this allowed me to do it leaving the ViewModel private and without having a DP.

Comment: This way allows interspersing two different ViewModels including on the same row and without causing multiple instances of the ViewModels

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you required-

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:VieModel}, Path=Test}"></TextBox>
<Controls:CustomControl x:Name="myControl" />
```

Don't forgot to add the markup extension to include the namespace where your class Viewmodel exists - `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewModel NameSpace"`